# How to remove the "Exit" option from the menu

Tags: docassemble

Currently I am using docassemble with a chat integration. I have disabled login by using the `show login: False` directive. Nonetheless, by doing this, now I am getting a "Exit" option in the menu of the interview. I would like to know if it possible to remove the "Exit" option, or control via python code the desired behavior of the exit option.

[image]

I've gone through most of the documentation https://docassemble.org/docs/config.html but haven't found anything useful.